# Convexity of cross entropy

Tags: information-theory, cross-entropy, convex

I am not sure if this is a better fit for this site or mathematics.stackexchange but I've seen similar questions on here before. I'd like to know if the following is true and if so, how I could go about proving it (just some hints will be enough):

For a fixed probability density $p$, the cross entropy $H(p, q)$ is convex in $q$, i.e. for any two probability distributions $q_1$, $q_2$:

$$
H(p, \alpha q_1(x) + (1 - \alpha) q_2(x)) \leq \alpha H(p, q_1) + (1 - \alpha) H(p, q_2)
$$

EDIT: gunes' answer gives a very nice explanation for the case in which $p$ and $q$ are discrete, but what about the continuous case? Can this be proven in a similar manner?

Comment: Yes, this is a good question for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-entropy can be written in terms of KL divergence: $H(p,q)=H(p)+D_{KL}(p||q)$. Since $H(p)$ is fixed, we can talk about the convexity of the KL divergence part.

The KL Divergence is [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#/Properties) for discrete $(p,q)$ pairs, i.e. for pairs $(p_1,q_1)$, $(p_2,q_2)$. Your question is a special case of this situation, i.e. if you set $p_1=p_2=p$.

[This](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Eanuprao/pubs/CSE533Autumn2010/lecture3.pdf) lecture note, if you're interested in the full proof, utilizes [log-sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_sum_inequality) to prove the convexity of the KL divergence.

Comment: That makes sense, I was originally trying to use the statement above to prove that the Kullback-Leibler divergence is non-negative so using it again to show convexity didn't cross my mind. But then again, the log-sum inequality only holds in the discrete case, I had continuous probability distributions in mind (I will add this to the question).

Comment: @gunes: Thanks, I have added the proof [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/entcross-conv).

Comment: can you please elaborate why did you neglect $H(p)$? the hessian on it is $\frac{d^2}{dp^2}H=-\sum\frac{1}{P(x)}$ which is negative thus concave. now you add convex (D) with concave function and the answer is unclear.

Comment: Because in the original post $p$ is fixed and therefore $H(p)$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If the inequality is true for any $x$ independently, then it is true for any sum over a subset of $x$.  Also, we know that $-log(x)$ is convex. What has to be true about $q(x)$ so that $-log(q(x))$ is convex? And is it true?

Comment: I believe I know what you're getting at. I'll try to work this out myself and edit my answer (I'll accept your answer in that case since it is more akin to what I was asking for originally).